# AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute '_jit_compile'

Tags: keras, bert-language-model

I'm trying to run bert use keras. But facing this problem. Can anyone help me? very thanks QQ

> AttributeError: in user code:
>
> File "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\bertdio\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\bertdio\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1006, in step_function  **
> if self._jit_compile:
>
> AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute '_jit_compile'

It's my code. When it run "outputs = old_train_function(inputs)" start have problem.

```
    def train_function(inputs):  # 重新定义训练函数
        grads = embedding_gradients(inputs)[0]  # Embedding梯度
        delta = epsilon * grads / (np.sqrt((grads**2).sum()) + 1e-8)  # 计算扰动
        K.set_value(embeddings, K.eval(embeddings) + delta)  # 注入扰动
        outputs = old_train_function(inputs)  # 梯度下降
        K.set_value(embeddings, K.eval(embeddings) - delta)  # 删除扰动
        return outputs

    model.train_function = train_function  # 覆盖原训练函数
```

I can't found any solution for same problem.
I run in keras2.8.0 but the original env is keras2.3.0 I think some code was change.